# Why are text elements inserted as elements in between the childNodes of a parent div?

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML below has a div with id `containerId` that has three child `div`s. A script tag gets the div with the id and prints out its `childNodes`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Child nodes</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="containerId">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const element = document.getElementById("containerId");
        console.log(element.childNodes)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The result in devtools is

```
NodeList(7)0: text
1: div
2: text
3: div
4: text
5: div
6: textlength: 7
__proto__: NodeList
```

**Why are those text elements there? I don't see this in a usual setup with all the other frontend layers when I'm using React. What is it that I need to do to avoid this?**

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of them? Instead of messing with the markup you might want to have a look at `.nextElementSibling` or check the `.nodeType` or use `.getElementsByTagName()`/`.querySelectorAll()` or ...

Comment: I guess I am so used to writing JSX in React and not messing with the usual DOM Api's that now this behaviour seems strange to me. My HTML file is being auto-formatted by prettier (and I like the result because it is more readable), but now there is this issue because I need to iterate over some childNodes.

Comment: Then just "ignore" them in the script. How I've already mentioned in my first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are carriage returns or empty spaces in your HTML.

You can use chrome dev tools (`View > Developer > Developer Tools`) and click the arrow next to each node after printing it out to console (`Console` tab) to see the details.

Here's another tip, if you type `$0` in dev console, it will target the exact node you have highlighted in the `Elements` pane... This will allow you to debug and investigate easily.

If you don't want that, remove the linebreaks and spaces from HTML like this: `<div></div><div></div><div></div>`.

[image]

Edit: Ok, there is one trick that you can use to prevent this (based on your comment). This is also used when you are centering items with `inline-block` and don't want the space to be visible on the page. You can space it like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Some text</div><div>
   Some text</div><div>
   Some text</div><div>
   Some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, sorry, I didn't write my question correctly: i know it is the whitespace, pretty obvious; but is the only way to avoid this to sacrifice readbility by bunching up the html like that?

Comment: Yes, correct. It is annoying, but there is one trick ill add to my answer

Comment: In general however, you shouldn't need to worry about whitespace at all. You can use the strategy above with `inline-block` because it visually affects the page. In your example, it's exactly how it should be so nothing needs to be 'fixed' at all.

Comment: @evianpring i saw your other comment. You can just use `getElementsByTagName('div')` so you only get div elements if you need to loop over them.

Comment: The reason for this question was to ask this other main question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58867864/does-setting-nodevalue-of-individual-text-elements-maximize-fps-when-updating-te

Answer (score 1):

The text nodes are the white space between the div tags. Edit your divs to be like the following and they'll go away:

```
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I know they are the whitespace, but is there no other way which preserves readability while also avoiding this problem?

Comment: @evianpring What "problem"? They are part of the DOM hence they will show up in the console.

Comment: @evianpring But they're legitimate nodes. Plus who cares what the underlying HTML looks like when you can prettify it using your built-in dev tools?

Comment: Ok, some context: what I really need to do is iterate over the children (well, the divs at least) and change their textContent. This is why I ran into this problem. And yes, prettier is auto-formatting my html as I posted.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your last question, you wish to iterate over the children, only the elements and not the nodes.

To do this you should use the children property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children

This allows you to target only the child **elements** and not all the child nodes.